# snapshot.val() returns undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a hard time getting a list of objects with Firebase. This code (in my service) is very straightforward, no mystery.

```
getObjs () {
  firebase.database ().ref ('obj')
    .once ('value', function (snapshot) {
      console.log (snapshot.val()); // this logs every object I ask for.
      return snapshot.val();        // this does not return nothing.
    });
}
```

It asks Firebase to retrieve the list of objects. The function returns `snapshot`, which is the result of the query, but here comes the weird part, when I call `console.log (snapshot.val())`, I get every object, but when I try to return the very same value using `return snapshot.val()`, I get nothing in my component.

Just in case, this is the function in the component:

```
constructor (private os) {
  this.objs = this.os.getObjs ();
}
```

I also tried to run for the same line of code (the one inside the constructor) in a lifecycle hook, but I get an infinite loop and crashes the app.

I updated the code this way, Service:

```
getObjs () {
  return firebase.database ().ref ('obj')
    .once ('value', function (snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val();
    });
}
```

Component:

```
this.os.getObjs ()
  .then (data => {
    this.objs = data;
    console.log (this.objs);
  });
```

With the `console.log (this.objs);`, I get the log of `W {A: P, W: U, g: ye}` and I absolutely don't know what to do with it. I tried (unsuccessfully) to cast the what I think is an observable to JSON.

Comment: Your `getObjs()` function doesn't return anything... I did't use `firebase.ref()` directly, but assuming it returns a promise, you can get the data: `this.os.getObjs().then(data => this.objs = data)` or something similar...

Comment: Ok, I sort of see what's happening. I tried to run the code that you say, but I get an error that says `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.`.  I modified my code in order to return a value. I'll edit my question in a second.